# How to stop the display of the native context menu on ios when using the QML TextInput

Tags: ios, qt, qml

I am using Qt5.7.1
In iOS long press on the QML TextInput displays the native context menu with Select/Select All/Paste items. How do i prevent this menu from showing, while allowing the TextInput to still be editable.

If i use Qt 5.6.2 the TextInput displays no such menu.

With the below code i am able to prevent the context menu from displaying in 5.7.1, however the cursor position always ends up at the end of the text.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Rectangle
{
 color: "yellow"
 width: 100; height: 100


 Rectangle {
     color: "white"
     width: 100; height: 50
     anchors.centerIn: parent


     TextInput{
         id:tip
         text:"test123"
         anchors.fill: parent

         onActiveFocusChanged: {
            console.log("tip onActiveFocusChanged")
         }
         onCursorPositionChanged: {
             console.log("onCursorPositionChanged:" + tip.cursorPosition )
         }


         MouseArea {
             id:ma
             anchors.fill: parent
             propagateComposedEvents:true

             onPressed: {
                 console.log("ma onPressed:" + tip.cursorPosition )
                 mouse.accepted = true
                 tip.focus = false;

             }

             onClicked: {
                 console.log("ma onClicked:" + tip.cursorPosition )
                 mouse.accepted = false
                 tip.forceActiveFocus();

             }

             onPressAndHold:{
                 console.log("ma onPressAndHold")
                 mouse.accepted = true
                 tip.focus = false;
             }
         }
     }
 }
}
```

I wonder if there is some better way i could do this and also have a fully editable TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

I could stop the edit menu from displaying on ios with the hack below :\

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Rectangle
{
    color: "yellow"
    width: 100; height: 100
    Rectangle {
         color: "white"
         width: 100; height: 50
         anchors.centerIn: parent

         TextInput{
             id:tip
             text:"test123"
             anchors.fill: parent
             MouseArea {
                 id:ma
                 anchors.fill: parent
                 propagateComposedEvents:true


                 onPressed: {
                     mouse.accepted = false
                     tip.focus = false
                     tip.focus = true
                 }
             }
             onSelectedTextChanged:tip.deselect()

         }
     }
}
```